# why is import alias in next js 12 not working?

Tags: typescript, next.js, import, refactoring

Here is my CompileOptions:

```js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    // "jsxImportSource": "@emotion/react",
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@/assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@/config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@/pages": ["pages/"],
      "@/public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@src/": ["src/"]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
  ],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    }
  ],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

In my project structure, I have all the listed paths in root directory.
I'm still getting this error:

> Cannot find module '@/src/containers/dashboard' or its corresponding type declarations.

[image]

When I add webpack config in next.config.js:

```
webpack(config) {
config.resolve.alias = {
  ...config.resolve.alias,
  '@': path.resolve(__dirname),
  '@/src/*': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/*'),
};
```

It compiles but still shows error in vs code.

Comment: Do you get errors when you transpile your project or is this only in your IDE?

Comment: I don't understand what this means. How do you configure webpack? Does it transpile without errors? Is this problem only with your IDE?

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer.

Comment: Is this `tsconfig.json` file involved in the build process? It's not valid JSON. Maybe it can't be read.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your configuration with a few tweaks and it worked for me. First set the `baseUrl` path to the `src` directory, and then restart your TS Server: `Ctrl + Shift + P` or `F1` > **TypeScript: Restart TS Server**.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "src/",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["*"],
      "@/assets/*": ["assets/*"],
      "@/config/*": ["config/*"],
      "@/pages": ["pages/"],
      "@/public/*": ["public/*"],
      "@src/": ["src/"]
    },
  },
}
```

Now you should be able to import your components as needed:

```
import Header from "@/containers/dashboard";
```

If you have JavaScript files in your project and you want to import them, I suggest setting `"allowJs": true`.

Comment: Thanks. Restart TS server works for me.